# Why the function does not return the value?

Tags: python, return, return-value, odoo

I didn't understand why the function does not return in python, My function counts the number of days (Friday and Saturday) between two dates but it does not return

**Here's my code :**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime
import calendar
calendar.setfirstweekday(calendar.SUNDAY)

from odoo import models, fields, api

class HrMission(models.Model):
    _name = "hr.employee.mission"
    _description = "hr mission"
    _inherit = "hr.employee.mission"

    days_compensation =fields.Float(compute='get_compensation', compstring='Jours de récupération', help="Jours de récupération si la mission contient les jours de repos",
                             required=True, readonly=True,)

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('mission_start_date', 'mission_end_date')
    def get_compensation(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.mission_start_date and rec.mission_end_date:
                time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(rec.mission_start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
                time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(rec.mission_end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
                week = {}
                leave_value = {}
        # Compute Number Of Friday And Saturday
                for i in range((time2 - time1).days):
                    day = calendar.day_name[(time1 + datetime.timedelta(days=i+1)).weekday()]
                    week[day] = week[day] + 1 if day in week else 1                    
                fri = week.get('Friday') if 'Friday' in week else 0  # Result Number 1 Of friday If "Start Date", "End date" --> "02/04/2019", "07/04/2019"
                sat = week.get('Saturday') if 'Saturday' in week else 0 # Same thing that Friday, Numbre 1 for Saturday
                friandsat = fri + sat # Result 2
                return friandsat
```

Comment: is this function returning `None`?

Comment: What do you expect `for rec in self:` to to?

Comment: compute method is just invoked when you define a field in view. try 'rec.days_compensation = monandsat'

Comment: it returns 0 in the field

Comment: @NabilTaleb that's float field's default value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign value on that field. For example, *rec.days_compensation = float_number*

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('mission_start_date', 'mission_end_date')
def get_compensation(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.mission_start_date and rec.mission_end_date:
            time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(rec.mission_start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
            time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(rec.mission_end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
            week = {}
            leave_value = {}
            # Compute Number Of Friday And Saturday
            for i in range((time2 - time1).days):
                day = calendar.day_name[(time1 + datetime.timedelta(days=i+1)).weekday()]
                week[day] = week[day] + 1 if day in week else 1                    
            fri = week.get('Friday') if 'Friday' in week else 0  # Result Number 1 Of friday If "Start Date", "End date" --> "02/04/2019", "07/04/2019"
            sat = week.get('Saturday') if 'Saturday' in week else 0 # Same thing that Friday, Numbre 1 for Saturday
            friandsat = fri + sat # Result 2
            rec.days_compensation = friandsat
```

Comment: @NabilTaleb Have you declare `days_compensation` field on view ?

Comment: Yes, i declared field in view, it's not a problem in the import library ! no ! because i use odoo all-in-one in windows, I really don't understand what is this problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `friandsat` at the starting and and the end of function return in outside of the for loop:

```
def get_compensation(self):
    friandsat = 0
    for rec in self:
        if rec.mission_start_date and rec.mission_end_date:
            time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(rec.mission_start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
            time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(rec.mission_end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
            week = {}
            leave_value = {}
    # Compute Number Of Friday And Saturday
            for i in range((time2 - time1).days):
                day = calendar.day_name[(time1 + datetime.timedelta(days=i+1)).weekday()]
                week[day] = week[day] + 1 if day in week else 1
            fri = week.get('Friday') if 'Friday' in week else 0  # Result Number 1 Of friday If "Start Date", "End date" --> "02/04/2019", "07/04/2019"
            sat = week.get('Saturday') if 'Saturday' in week else 0 # Same thing that Friday, Numbre 1 for Saturday
            friandsat = fri + sat # Result 2
    return friandsat
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the readonly Attribute where compute field is readonly in default unless inverse is given.
2. Make the field store = True
3. Update Code

   `@api.depends('mission_start_date', 'mission_end_date')
   def get_compensation(self):
       for rec in self:
           if rec.mission_start_date and rec.mission_end_date:
               time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(rec.mission_start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
               time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(rec.mission_end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
               week = {}
               leave_value = {}
               # Compute Number Of Friday And Saturday
               for i in range((time2 - time1).days):
                   day = calendar.day_name[(time1 + datetime.timedelta(days=i + 1)).weekday()]
                   week[day] = week[day] + 1 if day in week else 1
               fri = week.get(
                   'Friday') if 'Friday' in week else 0  # Result Number 1 Of friday If "Start Date", "End date" --> "02/04/2019", "07/04/2019"
               sat = week.get('Saturday') if 'Saturday' in week else 0  # Same thing that Friday, Numbre 1 for Saturday
               rec.days_compensation = fri + sat  # Result 2`